# Using mongo db in R

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write R script in which I have to do some operations on mongo database. Therefore, I have a few questions:

1. How to use double condition? I know how to use single condtion

   `mongoDB$find(query = '{"id" : { "$in" : ["1","2"]}}')`

   `mongoDB$find(query = '{"date" : { "$in" : "2019-08-09"}}')`

   How should I connect both conditions in one query? How to write such code?
2. How to use parameter in mongo code? In my script I will have vector with dynamic number of IDs. How I should write query? I am looking for something like:

   `VectorWithIDs <- c(1:1000)`

   `mongoDB$find(query = '{"id" : { "$in" : VectorWithIDs}}')`

Any Ideas how to solve both problems? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the query with a "," as a separation token.

For example:

`mongoDB$find(query = '{"id" : { "$in" : ["1","2"]}, '': "date" : { "$in" : "2019-08-09"}}'}')`